# typoscript bootstrap navbar working example

Tags: bootstrap-4, typo3

I use typo3 8 and want to move from bootstrap3 to bootstrap4.

Anyone else out there  with a working typoscript for bootstrap4 navbar?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for this ext:bootstrap_package It is very easily

https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package

Set it so

```
###################
#### FRAMEWORK ####
###################
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:bootstrap_package/Configuration/TypoScript/Bootstrap4/setup.typoscript">
```